google sheets, how to SWITCH with results to be a range?
I want to pick different ranges based on the value of a cell, here my formula
SWITCH(A1,1,M31:P35,2,R31:U35)
get this error: SWITCH has mismatched range sizes. Expected row count: 1. column count: 1. Actual row count: 5, column count: 4.
also tried to wrap ARRAYFORMULA around the range and INDIRECT, also the same results.
also tried to use IFS and I get the same error
Looking for a formula that will allow me to choose ranges.

Use let() and nested if() functions, like this:
=let( 
  range, 
    if(A1 = 1, M31:P35, 
    if(A1 = 2, R31:U35, 
    na() 
  )), 
  range 
)

Alternatively, use arrayformula(), like this:
=arrayformula( 
  if(A1 = 1, M31:P35, 
  if(A1 = 2, R31:U35, 
  na() 
)))



Formula 1
Save M31:P35 as Named_Range one & R31:U35 as two. then try:
=indirect(switch(A1,1,"one",2,"two"))

Formula 2
=if(A1=1,{M31:P35},if(A1=2,{R31:U35}))

